# Referencing folder ID from module - google terraform folders module and project factor module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I use the terraform modules **terraform-google-modules/folders/google** and **terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google**  and I cannot figure out how to reference one created folder that I need to use in the project factory module. The output seems to be IDS as well not one ID
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google/latest
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/folders/google/latest

I would like to reference the common folder ID so the project I create sits in the right folder hierarchy.
I read plenty of documentation and tried to find examples but everything I find around folders is the folder resources not folder module.

```
// setup folder structure in gcp
module "folders" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/folders/google"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  parent  = "folders/60860476666"

  names = [
    "development",
    "staging",
    "production",
    "common",
  ]

  set_roles = true

  prefix = "fldr"
  
  per_folder_admins = {
    dev = "group:gcp-organization-admins@mydomain.me"
    staging = "group:gcp-organization-admins@mydomain.me"
    production = "group:gcp-organization-admins@mydomain.me"
  }

  all_folder_admins = [
    "group:gcp-organization-admins@mydomain.me",
  ]
}

// setup logging project 
module "project-factory-logging" {
  source                  = "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google"
  version                 = "~> 14.0"
  random_project_id       = true
  name                    = "shared-logging"
  folder_id               = module.folder**s.????**
  org_id                  = var.organization_id
  billing_account         = var.billing_account
  default_service_account = "deprivilege"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `common` folder it, the following should be enough:

```
folder_id               = module.folders.folders_map["common"].name
```

Comment: Thank you. For my own learning/reference... where do I find in the manuals a reference to this ?   thanks

Comment: @JulianWiegmann On github https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-folders